# How to invoke lotus notes using Load runner

Tags: load, loadrunner

Can you please let me know how to invoke lotus notes using Load runner.
Is there any way to record lotus notes using vugen or we need to write code.

Regards
Archana Sapre

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Web based version of notes use a standard Web virtual user.

For the classical style there is no record model available.   Use the Notes API and a DLL-based virtual user (see VUGEN documentation for advanced concepts related to construction of virtual users with Visual Studio)

Comment: have you develop any load runner script for invoking lotus notes..?

Comment: A looong time ago and in a universe far away.   It is possible, but this will be a full on development effort.   There is nothing record and replay about the thick notes client.   Now, if you have a web version of notes server, just treat it like any other web app.    There will be lots of correlations for app identifiers under the covers but this is all within the domain of standard web stuff.